# !MESSAGE Referenced part does not exist yet: org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I am getting this error when running a tester plugin (using **SWTBot**), for my product:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-11-07 18:16:48.608
!MESSAGE Referenced part does not exist yet: org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer.
2013-11-07 18:16:48,611 main ERROR
```

Additionally, i get this exception that basically says that i haven't set my tester plugin as a dependency of my product:

```
Exception in thread "WorkbenchTestable" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Classloader found for plug-in com.project.test.swtbot
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.core.RemotePluginTestRunner.getClassLoader(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.core.RemotePluginTestRunner.getTestClassLoader(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.core.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.core.UITestApplication.runTests(UITestApplication.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.testing.WorkbenchTestable$1.run(WorkbenchTestable.java:71)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am using Eclipse RCP. Am i interpreting the error correctly? Does anyone have a clue of how to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone haveing this issue, you should always use (unless somethign creepy happens) "all workspace and enabled target plug-ins" in the launch configurations. This enables your test to validate every dependency that you might not be considering.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try Run Configuration -> Plugins -> Validate Plugins -> Add Required Plugins

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but already did that and the problem still persisted.